# How to handle Multi-Touch events with SkiaSharp? Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, multi-touch, skiasharp

Skiasharp enables to manipulate touch events with the method:

```
private void OnTouch(object sender, SKTouchEventArgs args)
```

With this method I can handle only one touch point coordinates:

```
args.Location.X, args.Location.Y
```

But how can I detect multitouch event?

The Android native API for example enables you to manage two finger locations in order to detect multitouch.

How can I achieve that with SkiaSharp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution for my question here is the code.

//Multitouch handling

```
Dictionary<long, SKPoint> dragDictionary = new Dictionary<long, SKPoint>();

    private void OnTouch(object sender, SKTouchEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.ActionType)
        {
            case SKTouchAction.Pressed:
                dragDictionary[e.Id] = e.Location;
                break;
            case SKTouchAction.Entered:
                break;
            case SKTouchAction.Moved:
                if (dragDictionary.Keys.Count > 1)
                {
                    dragDictionary[e.Id] = e.Location;
                    SKPoint? p1 = null;
                    SKPoint? p2 = null;
                    foreach (long key in dragDictionary.Keys)
                    {
                        if (p1 == null)
                        {
                            p1 = dragDictionary[key];
                        }
                        else if (p2 == null)
                        {
                            p2 = dragDictionary[key];
                        }
                    }
                    //MultiTouch handle
                }
                else
                {
                    //SingleTouch handle
                }
                break;
            case SKTouchAction.Released:
                dragDictionary.Remove(e.Id);
                break;
            case SKTouchAction.Exited:
                break;
        }
        // we have handled these events
        e.Handled = true;
        ((SKCanvasView)sender).InvalidateSurface();
    }
```